# I want to rewrite controller action method in MVC asp.net

Tags: asp.net-mvc, url-rewriting, routes

I have a controller in mvc named about. And in about controller i have a index method. It is running successfully with the url localhost:32275/about. But i want it to run with the url localhost:32275/about-us.

Help me with this.

Comment: rename the controller?

Answer (score 0):

You can use Attribute Routing for that. Have a read here
https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/webdev/2013/10/17/attribute-routing-in-asp-net-mvc-5/

This will enable you to have something like

```
[RoutePrefix("about-us")]
public class AboutController : Controller
```

Or

```
[Route("~/about-us")]
public ActionResult Index() { … }
```